# How to cast/parse API response from Node.JS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, api

I have a line of code in Node.js that call an external API:

```
public.getInfo(console.log, config.data1);
```

and retrieve some data:

```
null { abc:
   {field1: 0.234252,
   {field2: 0.234252,
   {field3: 0.234252,
   {field4: 1,
   {field5: 0.234252 },
{ xzy:
   {field1: 0.234252,
   {field2: 0.234252,
   {field3: 0.234252,
   {field4: 0.234252,
   {field5: 0.234252 }}
```

I can see the result in the console.  I have two questions:

1. `public.getInfo(console.log, config.data1);` has console.log as "callback" function.  What if I do not want to print this data, but just use it in other functions in my code?
2. How do I "read" the API response? How do I use the JSON structure of the response? For example: `abc -> fiels4 => 1`

Comment: You can only get the data via the callback function.

Comment: Remove `console.log` and replace with your callback function `function(err, data) {  // data will be your response }`

Comment: Great! at least now I have a better understand of the Callback function ;)

my new function is then:

public.getInfo(function(err,data){}, config.data1);


once I get the object "data", how do I browse/cast/parse it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure due to lack of code, but I think `config` is a variable you have set somewhere and you receive data from `config.data1`.

Use `config.data1[0].field4` to read the object property of abc -> field4 => 1

Or read the other ways to read properties https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right, I did not put much code here.... LOL

config is a variable that read some parameters from config.json... the callback is giving me now the 'data" object.

public.getInfo(function(err,data){}, config.data1)

but how to I read the data object casting "abc" -> field4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually founded a solution...

```
public.getInfo(function(err,data){  
console.log(data[config.data1].field4)
return true
},
config.data1);
```

This gives me the correct value of the returned API call... (in the console)...

But how to use the value outside the `public.getInfo` function? do I need to create a variable? confused

Comment: You don't. Once you are asynchronous, you have to stay async all the way down through the execution.  Look into [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Does it means that I need to use the API results inside the function? and eventually call a function inside this first function?

Long story short what I am trying to achieve is:

1) retrieve date from an API
2) manipulate the retrieved data
3) call another API including some parameters/data from the first API call...

Am I on the right path?

Thanks